# Bulk operation on various model instances

Tags: django

Apologies for this very generic question but is there a clean way to do basic operations (delete/update, etc..) on several model instance at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to run operations on multiple instances. To delete the 3 instances of your model, run:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(id__in=[model1.id, model2.id, model3.id]).delete()
```

If you have a queryset of the instances and some have a bool value set to True:

```
your_queryset.filter(bool_attribute=True).delete()
```

Comment: I think you'll need to share your form source code and the view in the question. It's only guessing until then :)